# How to get two digit numbers from alphabet assigned numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello friends I have code which is from others developers.

But I want to make a function like this but I get an error that Y is not defined

```
function nameNum(){

    A = I = J = Q = Y = 1;
    B = K = R = 2;
    C = G = L = S = 3;
    D = M = T = 4;
    E = H = N = X = 5;
    U = V = W = 6;
    O = Z = 7;
    F = P = 8;

    var text = "BANISETTINIRANJAN";
    text = text.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '');
    text = text.toUpperCase();
    var letters = text.split("")

    var num = (letters.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
        return prev + window[curr];
    }, 0));
    return nameNum();
```

But i get an error like Y is not defined

Comment: `Y` is not defined because you have not created the variable. e.g. `var Y=null`

Comment: You probably want to add to prepend the `A = I = 1;` with `var`. Also pretty sure you want to return the `num` var and not call `nameNum()` from within `nameNum()`. And properly close the function definition with `}`.

Comment: Also you probably want to pass the text as an argument, otherwise, `function nameNum() { return 47; }` does the same thing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Return call was wrong and function not closing properly**

1. Do not call the same function within a function using return
2. Inside the function  `Y` is defined one

**Updated**

send the name with function

```js
function nameNum(name) {

 A = I = J = Q = Y = 1;
  B = K = R = 2;
  C = G = L = S = 3;
  D = M = T = 4;
  E = H = N = X = 5;
  U = V = W = 6;
  O = Z = 7;
  F = P = 8;
console.log('y is '+Y)
  var text = name;
  text = text.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '');
  text = text.toUpperCase();
  var letters = text.split("")

  var num = (letters.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev + window[curr];
  }, 0));
  
  return num;
 
}

console.log(nameNum('bani'))
```

**updated with githup link solution**

just remove the `var`

```js
var mennt = 'bani'; 

function nameNum(name) {
 A = I = J = Q = Y = 1; //remove the var in this line 
  B = K = R = 2;
  C = G = L = S = 3;
  D = M = T = 4;
  E = H = N = X = 5;
  U = V = W = 6;
  O = Z = 7;
  F = P = 8;

  var text = name;
  text = text.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '');
  text = text.toUpperCase();
  var letters = text.split("")

  var num = (letters.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev + window[curr];
  }, 0));

  return num;

}

var naNumber = nameNum(mennt);
console.log(naNumber);
```

Comment: Hey Prasad How can I get text numbers.  Like if I type  any name "bani" in  var text = "BANISETTINIRANJAN"; then I get number which is assigned to each alphabet

Comment: If I type Bani i will get 9

Comment: thanks@prasad for helping me out. but I have encounter another error.
still Y is not defined with my code.
https://gist.github.com/baninaveen/7d3a34a8e49eb902cea4db5cb2275346

Comment: still getting an error i don't know why this is error image https://ibb.co/iUvqkF

Comment: Still getting Y is not defined plz help me out

Comment: is there any alternative to this @prasad

Answer (score 0):

```
function nameNum() {
                var x = {A:1, I:1, J:1, Q:1, Y:1, B:2, K:2, R:2, C:3, G:3, 
                L:3, S:3, D:4, M:4, T:4, E:5, H:5, N:5, X:5, U:6, V:6, W:6, 
                O:7, Z:7, F:8, P:8};

                var name = "Bani Naveen";
                var nameScore = 0;
                var name = name.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '');
                    name = name.toUpperCase();
                    var letters = name.split("")

                for( var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++ )
                {
                    var curChar = name.charAt( i );
                    var curValue = x[ curChar ];
                    nameScore = nameScore + curValue;
                }//for()

                console.log("your name number will be" + nameScore);
                return nameScore;
             }
```